# In Google Apps Script, how do I create, dispatch and handle a new event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, event-handling

I have the following js script such that when the event 'SayHelloEvent' is signaled, there are two separate handlers which will handle the event by logging a message to the console.

```
function signalSayHello() {
  var event = new Event('SayHelloEvent');
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}

document.addEventListener('SayHelloEvent', function SayHelloHandler1() {
  console.log('hello from Handler 1');
});

document.addEventListener('SayHelloEvent', function SayHelloHandler2() {
  console.log('hello from Handler 2');
});
```

Here's a js fiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/0egbsto9/

Now how do I rewrite this so that it works in Google Apps Script?

**Update:**
Ultimately the goal I'm after is to come up with a clean way to execute an "App function" at a time determined by a "Library function" that the "App" is calling. And I actually have a workaround that gets me the behavior that I'm after. But it involves passing functions as arguments. And this ends up looking a bit messy if I have to pass this functions as argument multiple times within the Library from one function call to another. Below is a simpler example where a script `MyScript` has a function `signalSayHello` receives an argument that gets executed as a function if it is indeed a function. And I have two App scripts named`App1` and `App2` which have access to this library and pass their own functions so they can be executed at a time determined within `MyLibrary`. So if I call the `sayHello` function from `MyApp1` then it will log to the console `Hello from MyApp1`, and from `MyApp2` it will log `Hello from MyApp2`. So I would like to re-write the code below to use events instead of having to pass functions as arguments.

**MyLibrary**

```
function signalSayHello(sayHelloHandler) {
  if (typeof sayHelloHandler === 'function' ){
    sayHelloHandler();
  }  
}
```

**MyApp1**

```
function sayHello() {
  MyLibrary.signalSayHello(function SayHelloHandler1() {
    console.log('hello from MyApp1');
  });
}
```

**MyApp2**

```
function sayHello() {
  MyLibrary.signalSayHello(function SayHelloHandler2() {
    console.log('hello from MyApp2');
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `HTML Service` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and `Now how do I rewrite this so that it works in Google Apps Script?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tedonoz I skimmed it and didn’t and find what I was looking for. I’m in the process of taking a closer look but have not found anything yet.

Comment: @Tanaike are you familiar Google Apps Script?

Comment: If you copy the entire contents of the JSFiddle code including the HTML into a new Googlr App Script HTML page and use [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) it works for me.

Comment: @TheWizEd right, it works if the the js code stays inside the html. But I would like it to work in the Code.gs file. For example if you copy the js code inside Code.gs and then run 'signalSayHello' then this will trigger a ReferenceError since 'document' is not defined inside of Google Apps Script.

Comment: That's because `document.addEventListener` creates a DOM event associated with your HTML page.  Google App Script (GAS) knows nothing about DOM.  There is no event listener in GAS, other than triggers.

Comment: @TheWizEd In GAS is there not a way to create a "new trigger" and configure it to only get triggered when one of my functions is called?

Comment: Maybe explain better what you are trying to achieve.  Like @Tanaike, I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  What do you mean "to only get triggered when one of my functions is called"?  How does your function get executed, from an HTML page, from a Google Spreadsheet, from a Google Web App?

Comment: @TheWizEd I have a script that I'm deploying as a library. And I want to be able to signal events from this library so that scripts that use this library can handle the event according to what they need. For example, I have a library that gets data from multiple data sources and updates various data sources. And I want to signal events to indicate which sources are getting updated or fetched. The handlers of the events may chose to log the event to the console, alert the user, etc...

Comment: You still haven't explained how your library functions are executed, from a Google Spreadsheet, from a Web App?  What is the user interface that the message should be sent to, Google Custom Dialog, Browser, Google UI alert?  Each of the things I have mentioned are handled differently.

Comment: @TheWizEd It's in Google Sheets. And there's various functions that could signal events. They could be called from built-in events such as onOpen. From custom menus. From functions that users enter into a spreadsheet cell. Or from the script editor itself by selecting the function and clicking Run or Debug since some of my users could be developers who just want to log events to the console.

Comment: What do you mean by "console"?  All of the things you mention can write to the execution log.

Comment: @TheWizEd By console I mean something like 'console.log("log message")'. And yes I can write logs during all the things I mentioned. But I only want to log when data transfer takes place within the Library. And there will be times when no data transfer takes place so there is no need to log anything. And log is just an example. Another example could be where a function entered in a cell ended up updating data source 'A' and I want to add a note the the cell saying something like "Data Source 'A' updated on 5/3/23 at 4pm". But the script that uses the library decides how to handle the events.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties?hl=en)

Comment: @TheWizEd I actually tried that out and it doesn't work. And the documentation even says "Properties are never shared between scripts."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Property Service to collect events as shown.  I create several functions.  After opening, editing, and running the scripts from script editor I get a collection of messages as shown in the exection log, the last being `onOpen()` but it hasn't added anything to the message queue yet.  I'm sure this could be simplified but this illustrates I can get Property Service from and script or context.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
    let props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    let prop = props.getProperty("TestScript");
    console.log("onOpen: "+prop);
    if( prop ) {
      prop = prop.concat("; Open");
    }
    else {
      prop = "Open";
    }
    props.setProperty("TestScript",prop)
}

function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    let props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    let prop = props.getProperty("TestScript");
    console.log("onEdit: "+prop);
    if( prop ) {
      prop = prop.concat("; Edit");
    }
    else {
      prop = "Edit";
    }
    props.setProperty("TestScript",prop)
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Error in onEdit: "+err);
  }
}

function script1() {
  try {
    let props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    let prop = props.getProperty("TestScript");
    console.log("Script1: "+prop);
    if( prop ) {
      prop = prop.concat("; Hello");
    }
    else {
      prop = "Hello";
    }
    props.setProperty("TestScript",prop)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in script1: "+err);
  }
}

function script2() {
  try {
    let props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    let prop = props.getProperty("TestScript");
    console.log("Script2: "+prop);
    if( prop ) {
      prop = prop.concat("; Goodbye");
    }
    else {
      prop = "Goodbye";
    }
    props.setProperty("TestScript",prop)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in script2: "+err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
May 3, 2023, 12:42:26 PM    Debug   onOpen: Hello; Goodbye; Hello; Goodbye; Edit; Edit; Edit
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in your example I have to run or trigger one of those functions in order to see a history of events that took place in the past. 

I'm looking for a way to capture an event at the moment it takes place in real time.

Comment: Everyone of the function are being run in real time. I guess I still don’t understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe [Spreadsheet.toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String))

Comment: I just updated my original post with an update which hopefully explains things a bit better.